# GCP's service account cannot read project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-google-cloud

My GCP organization has the following structure

```
mydomain.com
  - Root-project 
  - Development
      - my-project-name
```

In order to automate the project creation within my `Development` folder using terraform, I created a service account in the `Root` project and created an IAM principal in `Development` and granted `Project Creator` as well as `Project Deleter`.

My terraform script looks something like

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "4.68.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
  ]
}

resource "google_project" "project" {
  name = var.project_name
  folder_id = var.folder_id
  project_id = var.project_id
  billing_account = var.billing_account_id
}
```

When I run this script locally using glcoud CLI to authenticate on both my personal account and the service account everthing works fine.

When I run it after setting the credentials using the environment variable `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` I'm able to create the resources but if I run it again, as Terraform will refresh states, it throws this error

```
Error: Error when reading or editing Project "my-project-id": googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "googleapis.com",
│     "metadata": {
│       "method": "google.cloudresourcemanager.v1.Projects.GetProject",
│       "service": "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
│   }
│ ]
│ 
│ More details:
│ Reason: insufficientPermissions, Message: Insufficient Permission
```

I don't understand how can I be able to create a project but not able to fetch its data. In IAM I see that my service account has the `Owner` role on `my-project-name`.

Comment: **Looks SA was attempting to reach out to the cloud resource manager and couldn't due to an inactive API**. Check which scope allowed for this to occur, and enable all the API's as a temporary workaround. The possible root cause could be that since the **Service Management** scope can only be set to read-write, which still excludes it from making [IAM changes](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account.html), it’s unable to make the changes Terraform is enabling.

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy Wdym by service management scope ? Is it a IAM permission? 
Also the resource manager api was already enabled

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the CLI `gcloud` you might be using different credentials than Terraform is using. Terraform uses Application Default Credentials (ADC).

Run this [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) to make sure ADC is using the correct credentials:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

The API that has the permission problem is `google.cloudresourcemanager.v1.Projects.GetProject`

That API requires the permission `resourcemanager.projects.get`. [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-proj#permissions)

There are several [predefined IAM Roles](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-proj#using_predefined_roles) with that permission. Since you need to create projects, add the following role at the organization or parent folder level:

```
roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator
```

The crentials that ADC is configure for, does not have that permission or does not have that permission at the correct level (folder or organization).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but turned out that it was a dumb mistake. In my pipeline I wasn’t passing the key and instead of 401 I got 403 for whatever reason which was confusing. Now everything works perfectly